# How to get to the bottom of ScrollView after amount of time in android with Rxjava?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-android

I want to get to the bottom of an scroll view after some button has clicked, but I had trouble doing it:(.
thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to do this? , please explain more

Comment: it is complicated, just tell me how to achieve that

Comment: We can't help you unless you properly explain what you want to achieve. Please don't be rude and read up on [ask] on Stack Overflow.

Comment: why there are so many downvotes :((, my situation is complicated and I cannot explain it easily, I just wanted to do that:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with Rxjava but probably you should work on the scenario, to find a better way instead of this,
here's a guide which can help you.

```
 Observable.interval(400, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)//amount of time
                    .take(4)//as many times as you want
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribe(
                            onNext -> scrollView.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN)
                    );
```

Answer (score 1):

To get to the bottom of scroll view on button clicked you can do something like this:

```
public void onButtonClick(View view){
    ScrollView scrollview = ((ScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrl));
    scrollview.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scrollview.fullScroll(ScrollView.FOCUS_DOWN);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/43466232/edit) your answer to add an explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.